# Insert Multiple Records In One Connection

Tags: c#, sql, insert

I want to update a contactInfo database using C#.  I need to insert (possibly) multiple people/emergency contacts from a windows form.  So I am setting the textboxes on the windows form equal to variables to pass into my query.  I know how to do one record per connection, but how would I do two? so for example if a secondary emergency contact was supplied how could I also insert the data provided in txt2fname, txt2lname, txt2phone1, txt2phone2?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStringGoesHere")
{
SqlCommand cmd;
try
{
  string emergencyContactInfo = "Insert Into econtactInfo(fname, lname, phone1, phone2) Values(@fname, @lname, @phone1, @phone2)";
  cmd = new SqlCommand(emergencyContactInfo, con);
  con.Open();
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txt1fname);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithvalue("@lname", txt1lname);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone1", txt1phone1);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithvalue("@phone2", txt1phone2);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  connection.Close()
}
}
```

Comment: Are the other fields (`txt2fname`,...) in the same table?  If so, just add them into your existing statement.

Comment: Those fields are on the windows form.  The fields that would need to be updated are still fname, lname, phone1, phone2

Comment: keep connection open for the duration the window is open

Comment: @Jonesy how would I insert values from both sets of textboxes to the same fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to go something like this..

```
string emergencyContactInfo = "Insert Into econtactInfo(fname, lname, phone1, phone2)     Values(@fname, @lname, @phone1, @phone2)";
cmd = new SqlCommand(emergencyContactInfo, con);
con.Open();

cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.<Type>);
<Add the other parameters here>
...

cmd.Parameters["@fname"].Value = txt1fname
<Add parameters values here>
...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.Parameters["@fname"].Value = txt2fname
<Add parameters values here>
...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

connection.Close()
```

Comment: @Fabrico it says the SqlDbType.<string> 'Identifier Expected' and 'Invalid expression term 'string'

Comment: @MasterOfStupidQuestions SqlDbType is an enum, you have to change that for the type of your column/field. [SqlDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx). For example: cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar);

Comment: Oh good grief.  So sorry, had to change it to SqlDbType.NVarChar and it is now perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string SqlString =@"Insert into mytable(f1,f2) values ('1','2'),
Insert into mytable(f1,f2) values ('3','4'),
Insert into mytable(f1,f2) values ('5','6'), ";
con.Execute(SqlString);
```

Or something like this

```
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStringGoesHere")
        string emergencyContactInfo = @"Insert Into econtactInfo(fname, lname, phone1, phone2) Values({0}, {1}, {2}, {3})";
        con.Open();
for(....)
{
        con.Execute(String.Format(emergencyContactInfo ,txt1fname,txt1lname,txt1phone1 txt1phone2));
}
        connection.Close();
```